# Matlab - Class to which one can add different "items"

Tags: matlab, function, class

How would I go about doing (for example) something like this:

```
house = Building('blue'); % creates an object representing a 'blue' house 
                          % based on a class called building

room1 = Room('kitchen', 9);  % creates a room object representing a kitchen
                             %  with a size of 9 m^2  
room2 = Room('lobby', 5);    % creates a room object representing the lobby
                             %  with a size of 5 m^2  

house.add_room(room1);    % assigns the two rooms to the house object
house.add_room(room2);    %

house.room_count();       % should return the number 2
house.size('kitchen');    % should return the size of the kitchen, i.e. 9
house.size();             % should return the size of the entire house, i.e. 14
house.room_list();        % should return a list of the rooms in the house
                          %  which could e.g. be the string 'kitchen lobby'
```

This example is completely theoretical and I am only wondering how one would implement something like this in Matlab to see how the language works. I'd be grateful for any kind of help.
*My background is in the more "rudimentary" language of C++, but I want to learn Matlab. However, I don't seem to be able to find any useful code examples explaining these kind of things; hence this question.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your background is in C++, then you should be familiar with the concept of classes and objects.

Here is quick example implementing some of your design:

#### Room.m

```
classdef Room < handle
    properties
        name
        area
    end
    methods
        function obj = Room(name, a)
            if nargin < 2, a = 1; end
            obj.name = name;
            obj.area = a;
        end
    end
end
```

#### Building.m

```
classdef Building < handle
    properties
        color
        rooms
    end
    methods
        function obj = Building(clr)
            obj.color = clr;
            obj.rooms = Room.empty(1,0);
        end

        function add_room(obj, r)
            if ~isa(r, 'Room'), return, end
            obj.rooms(end+1) = r;
        end

        function num = room_count(obj)
            num = numel(obj.rooms);
        end

        function list = room_list(obj)
            list = {obj.rooms.name};
        end

        function sz = area(obj)
            sz = 0;
            for i=1:numel(obj.rooms)
                sz = sz + obj.rooms(i).area;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now we can create objects like you did:

```
house = Building('blue');
house.add_room(Room('kitchen',9));
house.add_room(Room('lobby',5));
house.room_count()
house.room_list()
house.area()
```

Comment: MATLAB has extensive documentation on the subject of object-oriented programming, so I'll just point you to the docs for more info: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/object-oriented-programming.html, http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/object-oriented-programming.html

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! And yes, I have looked at your references, but they didn't really explain things in-depth. And maybe one follow-up question. What if I had a super-class class called **house_part** and derived classes like **room** (i.e. classdef room < house_part) and **pipe** (classdef pipe < house_part). How would I go about adding those to the house? I guess the house would need a property like **parts** in the **Building** class and I would need to initialise **obj.parts = house_part.empty(1,0);** in the constructor? I am trying this, but it doesn't work. :/

Comment: actually everything you need is covered in the docs (the [empty()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html) method, [array of objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-object-arrays.html), [inheritance](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/creating-subclasses--syntax-and-techniques.html), [heterogeneous arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.heterogeneous-class.html), and much more..). I suggest you first go through the docs, read up on those topics, and if you had any question create a new posts.. Good luck

Comment: I solved the problem with cell-arrays: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html

Comment: yes that is definitely easier :) cell-array are general containers that can store any type.

Comment: But thanks a lot for your help. Matlab seems powerful, but its nuances/features are not easy to unravel. ;)

Comment: granted, the OOP part of the language is a bit clunky compared to traditional ones like C++/C#/Java, but it really shines with vectors, matrices, and N-D arrays..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would completely fit all of your requirements, but have you tried playing around with the structure class?

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/struct.html